# Concatenate the values of two pandas series (that are not of str type) is too slow (linear complexity)

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time-complexity

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with two (or more) series that are not of type `str` (type float for instance). The output I want to have is a serie of type `str` that is the result of the concatenation of my series (of type float) with a given separator (for instance "-").

The following function `build_df_ex` build the example dataframe:

```
def build_df_ex(n):
    df_ex = pd.DataFrame({"s1": -abs(np.random.rand(int(n))),
                          "s2": +abs(np.random.rand(int(n)))})
    return df_ex
```

The function `convert_to_str_and_add` make the desired concatenation :

```
def convert_to_str_and_add(df, sep="-"):
    df = df.astype(str)
    s = df.s1 + sep + df.s2
    return s
```

My main problem is that this function has linear complexity (see the graph below) which is prohibitive in my case. The **main bottleneck of the function is the conversion to `str` type**. I have try to go the numpy way but I didn't see any gain in performance, probably because it is what pandas is already doing under the hood.

[image: time complexity of the operation]

Anyone has a solution that would make this operation faster ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can not escape linear performance - your only hope is to show more of what you plan to do with the result to try and avoid extra work. What you have written is perfectly reasonable, you can try the following and see whether it has better performance (but I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't).

```
df.apply(('{0[0]}' + sep + '{0[1]}').format, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @orlp ! 
I had already tried something along those lines `df.apply(lambda row: "-".join((str(cell) for cell in row)), 1)` which has more or less the same performance as your solution. However the two solutions (using apply) are ~10 times slower than my initial solution (which might be faster because of vectorization ?)

Comment: @EtienneKintzler I'm not surprised. I'm afraid this is the end of the line then, unless you show how you use the formatted data that turns out to be in a way that's unnecessary.

Comment: My use case is the following : I have a dataframe df with columns col_a, col_b, col_c and a general formula defined as a string `"[col_a] | new_name_col_c:[col_c] new_name_col_b:[col_b]"`. You can imagine `"[ col_x]"` as being a placeholder for the values of the column x. The function outputs a list of string (of size df.shape[0]) where the element i of the list is a string `"df[col_a][i] | new_name_col_c:df[col_c][i] new_name_col_b:df[col_b][i]"` with `"df[col_x][i]"` being the value of column x at row i

Comment: @EtienneKintzler If you *have* to output a list of strings I'm afraid it's really end of the line and not much performance can be gained.